# Получить сообщения Facebook Graph Api

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

Пытаюсь получить сообщения с  `Graph Api`, делаю запрос:

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/me/inbox?access_token=EAACObiYvrpMBAFp5XOFDRWfJmZCwS1TRleCXn0XTD913GrMxw6jIqWI3x4BNNZBT8Re29ZAv4EYdW6hkcMrumfsZD"
```

в ответ получаю:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#298) Requires extended permission: read_mailbox",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 298,
    "fbtrace_id": "F/xWTSPKQ86"
  }
}
```

Разрешения `read_mailbox` найти в списке я не смог, но добавил: `read_page_mailboxes`.

Вопрос: как можно получить список сообщения для пользователя через `Graph Api`.

Comment: Судя по ошибке - нужно установить разрешение для приложения - "read_maiboxes".

Comment: @DonaldRump прочитайте мой вопрос еще раз!

Comment: извините, не заметил. Я когда-то тоже пробовал получить список сообщений, и не получалось. По-моему, facebook хочет что бы приложение прошло полную проверку.

Comment: Ну вот, по-ходу так и есть, я думал может есть какой то easy-способ!